Dockerfile: deploy Azure Function error gRPC channel URI 'http://:' could not be parsed
I try to create a docker image of an Azure function and to run it in a container on docker desktop (and AKS later).
I cannot change the project type, it must be an Azure function running on .net 8.
Solution structure:

Solution File
Dockerfile.MyApi
MyNamespace.MyApi (Azure Function)

MyApi.csproj => loads the Common library


MyNamespace.Common (Library)

Common.csproj



I can build the image, but when I try to run it in a container, I get the following error:
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://:' could not be parsed.
My dockerfile looks like this:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-preview AS installer-env
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj files and restore as distinct layers
COPY "MyNamespace.MyApi/*.csproj" "MyNamespace.MyApi/"
COPY "MyNamespace.Common/*.csproj" "MyNamespace.Common/"
RUN dotnet restore "MyNamespace.MyApi/MyNamespace.MyApi.csproj"

# copy and build app and libraries
COPY "MyNamespace.MyApi/" "MyNamespace.MyApi/"
COPY "MyNamespace.Common/" "MyNamespace.Common/"
WORKDIR "/source/MyNamespace.MyApi"
RUN dotnet publish -o /app

# Print the content of the /home/site/wwwroot directory
RUN ls -l /app

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/app \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/app", "/app"]

# Set the entry point for the Azure Functions host
ENTRYPOINT ["./app/MyNamespace.MyApi"] # the container runs without this Entrypoint command, but the function is not found


Without the ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile I can run the container, but it seems not to find the Azure function (hence doesn't work correctly).
My program.cs of the Azure function "MyApi" looks like this:

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() // error happens on this line
    ...
    .Build();

host.Run();


Docker Desktop:

My docker commands in powershell:
Build:
docker build -t myUrl.io/crm/crm-myapi-image -f Dockerfile.MyApi .

Run:
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name crm-myapi-container myUrl.io/crm/crm-myapi-image

Do you know how to solve this error?

You need to include your docker run command as well. This seems to be a configuration problem.

Thanks for your reply. I added the commands (Build and Run) to the question. I can start the app without ENTRYPOINT ["./app/MyNamespace.MyApi"], but the function does not run correctly (not found). Do you have another idea?

@Bender can you share your code?

@Bender, Modify your dockerfile as shown in image.


Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://:' could not be parsed.

I used .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() in my Program.cs file.
Below given Dockerfile and functions file worked for me.
My Directory :

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4.0-dotnet-isolated8.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]

Httptrigger.cs:
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace csharp_docker
{
    public class Httptrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Httptrigger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Httptrigger>();
        }

        [Function("httptrigger")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();

csharp_docker.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.15.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

OUTPUT:




Hi, thanks for your answer. In my case I need to reference a shared library. If I add the Dockerfile to the project level, I haven't found a way to reference the external library yet. I would have to put the Dockerfile at the solution level - but that leads to the grpc error... do you have any other idea?

@Bender. try adding the shared library's project reference to you current project .csproj file and you need to add or copy the shared library project to container then you can mention the COPY path/of/shared/library/project  current/docker/directory in dockerfile.
